# Does myeclipse 8.6 supports spring 3.0

Tags: java

I installed myeclipse 8.6 on windows 8. When i am adding spring 3.0 web libraries it is not supporting. But it is supporting 2.5. Can any one please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Spring Tool Suite, also known as Eclipse STS instead, see here some [snapshots](http://spring.io/tools/sts).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest release of MyEclipse (currently the 2014 release). It's best to keep up to date with releases as they are more likely to have recent releases of framework libraries. Your MyEclipse license allows you to install all releases of MyEclipse whilst your license is valid; licenses do not apply to a single release.